# Regular expressions in python where text is read from file

Tags: python, regex, file, match

I have regular expression that scans some data from html files
the code is removing **html** tags using *BeautifulSoup* and return the following text (just a part from the text):

/Semester:
2011 / 1
Number :
20112222

Name                   :
XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
Advisor

This sample of my code:

```
import re,glob,os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk

path = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\data_tools\\transcripts'
os.chdir(path)
delch=','

def scantext(text,snum) :
    re_semstudent = re.compile("Semester:\s*(\d*)\s*\/\s*(\d)\s*Number\s*:\s*(\d{8})\s*Name\s*:\s*(.*)\s*Advisor")
    semesters = text.split("Year")

    for ind in range(1,len(semesters)):
        s = semesters[ind]
        x = re.search(re_semstudent,s)
        if x :
            year=x.group(1)
            semester=x.group(2)
            studentid=x.group(3)
            studentname=x.group(4)

        print year+"#"+semester

    return 0

ii=1
for fname in glob.glob("*.html") :
    f = open (fname)        
    text = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser').getText()
    scantext(text,ii)
```

When I am trying the *re.search* with the text as fixed string, its work fine!
But when I send the text in the *scantext* function and use the  `semesters = text.split("Year")`. I can print the text of each split, but the regular expression can't match any value!

Comment: Why are you using a regex to parse html when you are using Bs4 already? Would it not be easier use the tags to get what you want?

Comment: yes it's easier without the tags, but that's not the problem while the regular expression is working correctly with text. maybe the problem is with how i am reading the file, but i don't know

Comment: Maybe share a bit of the html and explain what you want to get and it will be easier to suggest something. You can combine a re.compile with bs4 so I still think it can all be done using bs4

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j3o54fyez14es0c/201122.html?dl=0 
this is one html, i am trying to extract all informations from the html and save them in a csv file. actually the actual python scripts worked before on Mac with "text = nltk.clean_html(f.read())" but in windows i get an error with nltk so i used bs4 then i have this problem.

Comment: What do you actually want from the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [`re.U/re.Unicode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag:

```
  re_semstudent = re.compile("Semester:\s*(\d*)\s*\/\s*(\d)\s*Number\s*:\s*(\d{8})\s*Name\s*:\s*(.*)\s*Advisor",re.U)
```

Which if you run after will give you something like:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe9fb721df8>
2011#1
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe9fb721d50>
2011#2
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe9fb721df8>
2012#1
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe9fb721d50>
2012#2
```

You might also need to open the file with `encoding="utf-8"`:

```
from io import open
for fname in glob.glob("*.html") :
    with open(fname, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        text = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser').getText()
        scantext(text, ii)
```